# How to create Stale NFS file handle?

Tags: bash, handler

I need to test script that deletes stale NFS file handles, so I would like to prepare a sample. Which way is simplest?
Thanks.

Comment: How would you delete a stale NFS file handle? The file is already deleted, but the client doesn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a super-hacky way that I do it.

**in 1 terminal**

> vim tmp.tmp

**in a second terminal**

> rm -f tmp.tmp.swp

This should generate a **.nfs#####** file.